# How do I read data from MongoDB using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

In the MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#examples) it says to do something like:

```
db.bios.find()
```

In my code I have this portion:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/eBookStore');

let newBookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  bookName: {type: String},
  bookSubtitle: {type: String},
  publicationDate: {type: Number, default: new Date().getTime()}
});

let Book = mongoose.model('books', newBookSchema);

db.Book.find();
```

where 'eBookStore' is the name of my database and 'books' is my collection name. I know the place where I typed 'db' in 'db.Book.find()' is incorrect, but I don't know what the code there should look like when referencing the database. Please help!

Comment: I have an public app using nodejs and mongoose here. May this help you https://github.com/dangminhtruong/havana

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You are having this is your schema
> 1. bookName
> 2. bookSubtitle
> 3. publicationDate
> So with using any of the you can find the schema details
> You have create the function like below to search the book schema from anywhere

```
public getBookDetails(name, callback: CallableFunction) {
        Book.find({bookName: name }, (err, book) => {
            if (err) {
                callback(err);
            } else {
                callback(book);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/eBookStore',{useNewUrlParser:true});

//Schema model
let newBookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  bookName: {type: String},
  bookSubtitle: {type: String},
  publicationDate: {type: Number, default: new Date().getTime()} // i will have used new Date() only for future data query based on date
});

let Book = mongoose.model('Book', newBookSchema); // Capital letter will be better for distinguish from a normal variable and to remember easly
```

Let say you want to see or "read" a specific book with a specific id, for that you can  create a router and read the data.

```
app.get('/view/:id', (req, res) => {

    var bookId = req.params.id;

    //read the data part 
    Book.findOne({ _id: bookId }, (err, oneBook) => {

        if (err) console.error(err);

        //pass data to the template engine
        res.render('book/sale', { oneBook });

    });
       // Or you can use findById()

    Book.findById({ bookId }, (err, oneBook) => {

        if (err) console.error(err);

        //pass data to the template engine
        res.render('book/sale', { oneBook });

    });
});
```

if you want to get all the books :

```
 app.get('/allbooks', (req, res) => {
    //find all books
    Book.find({}, (err, allBooks) => {

        if (err) console.error(err);

        res.render('book/list', {allBooks})
    })
});
```

Let say that you want to get books between two dates selected by the user from the html template by using a form with action "/daterange" and method POST

```
app.post('/daterange', (req, res) => {

    //date input from template engine named start
    var startDate = new Date(req.body.start);

    //date input from template engine named end
    var endDate = new Date(req.body.end);

    Book.find({ "publicationDate": { "$gte": startDate, "$lte": endDate } }, (err, booksByDate) => {

        var startDate = new Date(req.body.start); // this is why you should use new Date() only for query simplicity

        var endDate = new Date(req.body.end);

        if (err) console.error(err);

        res.render('book/bookbydate', { booksByDate});
    });
});
```

Let say you want the latest book : On the same principle

```
Book.findOne().sort({ publicationDate: -1 }).limit(1).exec((err, oneBook) => {
        if (err) console.error(err);
    //or do wahtever with you like with this oneBook
}
```

if you want to get the 2nd to the lastest

```
Book.find({}).limit(2).sort({ "_id": -1 }).exec((err, bookSecondLatest) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    // do what ever you want
});
```

Search by bookName

```
 Book.findOne({bookName: 'Game of thrones'}, (err,oneBook) =>{
    console.log(oneBook); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the documentation for mongoose

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Going specific to model use the link below
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Ex
let Book = mongoose.model('Book', newBookSchema,'books');

//First argument is mongoose model name , second schema and third name of collection in mongodb

Book.find({}}, function(err, arr) {});

Answer (score 1):

Using your same code, once you have connected mongo via mongoose you can make the search directly, no need to mention db. This always works if you have a schema of the collection you want to search in.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/eBookStore');

let newBookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  bookName: {type: String},
  bookSubtitle: {type: String},
  publicationDate: {type: Number, default: new Date().getTime()}
});

let Book = mongoose.model('book', newBookSchema);

Book.find({queryForFilters});
```

Notice I removed the 's' in books in line 9 of your code. This is because mongoose sotes the first argument in plural ang lowercase so passing book as the first argument will result in a collection named books.